# Reduction between two languages and a common one

Tags: computability, automata

My question is as following :
Let $A$ and $B$ be some languages, 
there exist a language $C$ such that $A\le C$ and $B\le C$, where "$\le$" means "reducible to", so $A\le C$ means there is a mapping $f$ from the strings over $A$s alphabet to strings over $C$s alphabet such that $x\in A$ iff $f(x)\in C$.

I need to either prove it or find an example to contradict the statement

I'm not really sure on how to solve such thing. May anyone help?

Edit :
Well, After thinking for some while I managed to conclude we need to define $C$ such that it will include both $A$ and $B$,
So I defined $C$ as follows :
$$C = \{0w\mid w \in A\} \cup \{1w \mid w \in B\}$$

Now I defined the reduction function :
$$
f(x) =\begin{cases} 
         0x & \text{if $x \in A$}\\
         1x & \text{if $x \in B$}
      \end{cases}
$$

the problem now is that I want to show either $x \in A$ iff $f(x) \in C$ or $x \in B$ iff $f(x) \in C$,
but the fact $x$ isn't in $A$ does not conclude $f(x)$ not in $C$ so I tried  $f(x) \in C$ iff $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. but I'm not exactly sure it's alright, may anyone help?

Comment: What is the source and context of this question? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Are these languages sets of strings, or sets of numbers? That will affect some details of the answer. Some context about your class would be very helpful.

Comment: It's in the context of Reduction. Sigma is (0,1)

Comment: @Tai And the source?

Comment: It's a question from an assignment in a course called Automata and Formal Languages.

Comment: Can't you just take $C=0\cdot A \cup 1\cdot B$?

Comment: @xavierm02 can you explain?

Comment: @xavierm02: why not write up an answer?

Comment: I did a bunch of formatting to your post. Check it to see that I didn't inadvertently change your original meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Your $C=0A\cup 1B$ will work, but to have $A\le C$ and $B\le C$ you'll need to have *two* mapping reductions: $f_1:\Sigma_A\rightarrow\Sigma_C$ and $f_2:\Sigma_B\rightarrow\Sigma_C$ such that $x\in A\Longleftrightarrow f_1(x)\in C$ and $x\in B\Longleftrightarrow f_2(x)\in C$.

Define 
$$
f_1(x)=0x\qquad f_2(x)=1x
$$
Now it's easy to see that $f_1$ gives a mapping reduction $A\le C$: if $x\in A$ then $f(x)=0x\in C$ and if $x\notin A$ then $0x\notin C$ (since any string in $C$ starting with $0$ must be followed by a string in $A$). The same reasoning gives a reduction $B\le C$ using $f_2$.

By the way, welcome to the site!

Comment: You are right, this will work only for $A,B \in R$. there is a way to build it for every two languages?

Comment: @automata123. Yes, see my edited version. I don't know what I was thinking last night.

Answer (score 0):

It can work for any language $A$ and $B$.

Let $f_1(x)=0x$, let $f_2(x)=1x$ and define $C$ as you did :

$$C = \{0w\mid w \in A\} \cup \{1w \mid w \in B\}$$

Hence $f_1$ and $f_2$ are recursive, and $A<C$ by $f_1$ and $B<C$ by $f_2$, and $A$ and $B$ can be any language (recursive or non).